# Django: accessing raw urls of form media in templates

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

`{{ form.media.js }}` and `{{ form.media.css }}` are great to easily include media in Django templates.

My problem is that I would like to get access to the raw urls (without `<\script type="text/javascript" src="raw_url"><\/script>`) of these media (to include them using `headjs`).

I'd like to achieve something like that:

```
<script>
{% for script in form.media.js %}
    head.js("{{ script.raw_url }}");
{% endfor %}
</script>
```

Comment: Moreover, calling head.js as many times as many scripts you have, won't give you any benefit. http://headjs.com/

Comment: I think you did not understand my question: "{{ script.raw_url }}" does not exist in django. You just have a block {{ form.media.js }}, which is replaced by: <\script type="text/javascript" src="url1"><\script>... I'd like to get this "url1"

Comment: And I want to call head.js this way for scripts to be loaded in parallel.

Comment: I just found this url, which explains the same problem as mine: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/QD1wSWV3qEQ does not seem to have any solution :(

Comment: @geux, I know you want to call head.js but i posted a link to documentation in my comment - you should call it once like `head.js(script_url_1, script_url_2, ..., script_url_n, optional_callback)`. Your loop would output multiple calls of head.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at source code of Media class there will be a function:

```
def render_js(self):
    return [u'<script type="text/javascript" src="%s"></script>' % self.absolute_path(path) for path in self._js]
```

So you can go the same way. Since we can't use underscored attributes in templates we can add method to the form class like this and use it:

```
from django import forms

class TestForm(forms.Form):
    def get_media_js(self):
        return [self.media.absolute_path(path) for path in self.media._js]
```